# Removing all xsl:if tags from xslt using Java

Tags: java, xslt

Is there any way I can remove all `xsl:if` tags from xslt?

I have an xslt from which I want to retrieve all the tag names. I do not have access to input xml for which this xsl is written so I have made dummy xml and applied xsl on that to generate output.xml, and from that output.xml I am retrieving the names of all nodes. But the problem is that in the xsl there are `if` conditions to check if particular value is not null then only that tag will be written to output xml. So is there any way to remove all xsl:if tags from xslt?

dummy xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
</map>
```

xsl code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">


<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/map">

<xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
<xsl:text>Test</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:if test="@TRANSACTIONDATETIME != ''">
<xsl:element name="TransactionDateTime">
<xsl:value-of select="@TRANSACTIONDATETIME"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@CHANGEINDICATOR != ''">
<xsl:element name="ChangeIndicator">
<xsl:value-of select="@CHANGEINDICATOR"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

No when i apply this xsl to my dummy xml output xml does not include tags with if conditions.

So i want to remove all if conditions from xslt so that i can generate xml as i want.

Expected output i want is xslt with no xsl:if tag :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">


<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/map">

<xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
<xsl:text>Test</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:element name="TransactionDateTime">
<xsl:value-of select="@TRANSACTIONDATETIME"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="ChangeIndicator">
<xsl:value-of select="@CHANGEINDICATOR"/>
</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note : I can not modify dummy xml to include the values for transaction date and change indicator because there are thousands of xslt on which i want to perform this actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- Identity template, copies everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Special template for xsl:if, only copies content -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:if">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response